# iOS objective sort dictionary by quantity

Tags: ios, json, nssortdescriptor

I'm new to iOS development, and I'm in problem that I don't know how to solve it...

I have JSON:

```
{
    "038b7af5-2874-448b-88c3-f667908723d8" = {
        Name = "Coffee";
        Quantity = 5;
    };
    "4d63daaf-962b-4382-a90e-dd4db0ce052e" = {
        Name = "Water";
        Quantity = 1;
    };
    "693a6897-4250-4eef-8164-3bb1812315fc" = {
        Name = "Fruit frappe";
        Quantity = 1;
    };
    "778a66df-a2ec-419f-b9dc-94e0c0fef40d" = {
        Name = "Fruit nes frappe";
        Quantity = 1;
    };
}
```

What I want to do is to sort them in `UITableViewController` by quantity. I tried `NSSortDescriptor` but with no success...
Thanks in advance, 
Stefan

Comment: You should have sorted this in server side..

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I don't have server yet, so I'm testing it locally...

Comment: @0yeoj: How do you propose to send a sorted JSON dictionary? And if the app has a "Sort" button that allows sorting by name, how do you propose to send a JSON dictionary sorted by quantity, and sorted by name at the same time?

Comment: @gnasher729: Is that stated in the question? That he has a **Sort** button? I'm sorry maybe my eyes is playing with me.. and i get your point, (maybe that's what he want to do after this) I got it~that's what i thought after he replied to my comment, and the answer below is pretty awesome i believe that one is what he is looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered collection types.

To order the tableview you need to use an additional array (which can be ordered) of the dictionary keys.

So to populate item `0` of the tableview you get the key from the array at index `0` and then get the column values from the dictionary entry with that key.

In order to sort this array by `Quanitity` you do this:

```
@property (readonly) NSMutableArray *arrayIndex;
@property (readonly) NSMutableDictionary *dataDict;
```

...

```
[arrayIndex sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *keyA, NSString *keyB) {
    NSDictionary *dictA = _dataDict[keyA];
    NSNumber *quantityA = dictA["Quantity"];
    NSDictionary *dictB = _dataDict[keyB];
    NSNumber *quantityB = dictB["Quantity"];
    if (quantityA.integerValue > quantityB.integerValue)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else if (quantityA.integerValue < quantityB.integerValue)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    return NSOrderedSame;
}];
```

Free tip: Don't store data in dictionaries if you can avoid it; instead convert the dictionary to a custom object as soon as possible as custom objects bring so much power and flexibility to your code, and look how much code I had to write just to make a comparator.

Comment: Nice answer. Just to note that this could be simplified even more by taking advantage of `compare:` (instead of manual comparison); though I guess the expanded form is good for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: @Alladinian Indeed.  I want to encourage custom objects rather than dictionaries of dictionaries anyway, so the worse it looks, the better :D

Comment: :P Agreed, but experience says that people are often not discouraged by that :/